# Convert local datatime string to python datatime object

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using Sendgrid-python and sender's email date comes as a format
"Fri, 22 Dec 2023 17:23:41 +1100".
I like to store this to postgres database but I have no clear idea of how to convert the above string to python data time object or similar?

Comment: [strptime official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 17:23:41 +1100"
date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)

print(datetime_object)
```

Output:

```
2023-12-22 17:23:41+11:00
```